Network Load Balancer and ARR IIS Web Farm on different Subnets
Here is my setup:
Primary Site - Cluster IP 192.168.10.X/192.168.200.X (Heartbeat):
2x NLB servers with ARR and IIS web Farm
2x WEB servers with 2 sites (both web servers have a copy of the same site on them)
Secondary Site - Cluster IP 192.168.20.X/192.168.200.X (Heartbeat):
2x NLB servers with ARR and IIS web Farm
2x WEB servers with 2 sites (both web servers have a copy of the same site on them)
Both sites are in different locations and can talk to each other by Site-to-Site VPN, I can ping each other site without issues, can RDP to either server. All servers are connected to the same Domain and the DC is located on Primary Location.
Primary site was first built and web farm consisted of only the 2 servers, then I added the second site with servers. I am able to add all web servers to the farm and I am seeing traffic onthe Monitoring and Management screen.
I am unable to add the NLB servers to the same cluster in either location. When I try connecting to one of the servers in other location through NLB Manager it only shows me the Heartbeat IP, even if I try by domain name or IP. I tried adding the cluster IP but my network stopped working.
For the DNS, I am using a URL with SSL and I created an A record on Amazon Route 53 to map mysite.mydomain.com to 192.168.10.X IP and also added the secondary site cluster IP. So if I ping the URL it will randomly change the IP. I wanted to create a health check on Amazon but it doesn't work with internal IPs and I don't want to set a public IP for my site as it is used for internal purposes to our other sites.
Why can't I connect primary or secondary NLB servers to each others cluster? What can I do for the DNS? If Primary goes down, then the sites won't work as it depends on which IP it gets, if it's on the primary IP then it won't work until it changes to secondary and if it changes in between then site goes down again.
I tried what I wrote above.
